# Testing onChange function in input's tag in inner component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create test cases for dome project I have

Here is the source code

```
const InputComponent = () => (
<div>
    <input type="text" value={this.props.val} onChange={this.props.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
</div>
)


const InnerComponent = () => (
<div>
    <InputComponent
        val={this.props.value}
        onInputChange={this.props.onInputChange.bind(this)}
    />
</div>
)


class MyComponent extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        val: ''
    }
}

onInputChange = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.setState({val});
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
           <InnerComponent
                val={this.state.val}
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
           /> 
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

So, I'm trying to test the onChangeInput function that occurs on onChange event of input tag at InputCompoent

I've tried to test it with jest.fn(), but I've got errors when I tried to simulate change on input

```
test(should test input change, () => {
const value = "coffee";
const onChangeInput = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
wrapper.find('input').simulate(change, {target: value}); <----here I gets error coz input not found in dom
}
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: In this case you will use mount instead of shallow. Shallow do not render child component.

Comment: Check that your `<InnerComponent/>` has property `val`  and you are trying to access that value like `this.props.value` and not `this.props.val`, so that's probably one issue. On the other hand, **shallow rendering** from enzyme only creates a **shallow** copy of the component (no children inside of it), maybe you should use `mount` in this case

Comment: Also `{target: value}` is incorrect. Should be `{target: {value}}`

Answer (score 0):

it should be {target:{value:'abc'}}